# Help encoding a cURL argument (works fine from the command line, but not from a PHP script)

Tags: php, curl

I am working with the Facebook API, and successfully use the following command via terminal to post a message to another users wall.

```
curl -F 'access_token=XXXXXXXXXX' \
 -F 'message=Hello World' \
 -F 'to={["id":XXXXXXX]}' \
 https://graph.facebook.com/me/feed
```

This works great.  I am trying to do the same via php with this code;

```
$fields = array(
    'access_token' => $t,
    'message' => $message,
    'to' => '{["id":'.$id.']}'
);

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,  $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);          
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields);
curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

This code successfuly posts a message, but it does it to my OWN wall (i.e. it is ignoring the 'to' parameter).  I'm new to cURL, and I'm sure I am encoding it wrong, or maybe missing a cURL flag, but I've been through several tutorials on POSTing via cURL, including a few SO answers, and I can't see what I'm missing.

Really appreciate any help!

Answer (score 1):

What does this print out?

```
if ( 'POST' == $_SERVER[ 'REQUEST_METHOD' ]) {
    echo 'Posted: ';
    print_r( $_POST );
    exit;   
}


$t = '121';
$message = 'helo Worlds';
$id = 1234;

$fields = array(
    'access_token' => $t,
    'message' => $message,
    'to' => '{["id":'.$id.']}'
);

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,  'http://localhost:8888/testbed/' ); // THIS script
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);          
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE );

$out = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

echo 'Received[ ' . $out . ' ]';
```

Prints this on my local box:

```
Received[ Posted: Array ( [access_token] => 121 [message] => helo Worlds [to] => {[\"id\":1234]} ) ]
```

Comment: That looks the same, except I do not see escaped quotes around \"id\", I just have "id".

Comment: It looks good, but something is making it different from the command line snippet I posted, as they have different results, with only the command line method respecting the value in the "to" paramter.  But thank you for the effort, and I like your debugging technique.

Comment: Thank you! Very interested to learn what made the two requests different.

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATED:**

$fields should be a [GET like string](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php)

```
  para1=val1&para2=val2&...
```

or an array:

> The full data to post in a HTTP "POST"
>   operation. To post a file, prepend a
>   filename with @ and use the full path.
>   The filetype can be explicitly
>   specified by following the filename
>   with the type in the format
>   ';type=mimetype'. This parameter can
>   either be passed as a urlencoded
>   string like
>   'para1=val1&para2=val2&...' or **as an**
>    **array with the field name as key and**
>    **field data as value**. If value is an
>   array, the Content-Type header will be
>   set to multipart/form-data. As of PHP
>   5.2.0, files thats passed to this option with the @ prefix must be in
>   array form to work.

Comment: Am I missing something? Doesn't it say "or as an array with the field name as key and field data as value"? It should be okay that it sets the content-type header if I do that, no?

Comment: No, you are right! My fault. And ugly documentation: The whole section in the PHP man page has a title like 'when to pass a string parameter'. Please excuse. Not my evening, after a very successful coding day ;-)

Comment: No worries! Thanks for the time! Let me know if something else jumps out at you ;)